# Using the Heine-Borel theorem to show compactness of an ellipsoid

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that $E$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where
$$E=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\;\middle|\;\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9} =1\right\}$$

Now boundedness, doesn't that require a metric? Well, if I use the Euclidean metric (maybe I need to use this metric to employ the Heine-Borel theorem), take $O=(0,0,0)$ and then $d(O,x)\lt 5$ for all $x\in E$. Hence $E$ is bounded.

Now I need to show that $E$ is closed.

How would I show closure? I can 'see' that all neighborhoods of a point will have another point within them. But I am not sure how to show this properly

Comment: You're missing $\le1$ in the defining conditions, I believe.

Comment: @egreg Sorry haha

Comment: to show closure, you might show that $E$ is the inverse image of a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ through a continuous function...

Comment: Observe that E is the level set of a continuous function. Does that help?

Comment: @JónÁskellÞorbjarnarson What is a level set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the set is closed, let $\{ (x_n,y_n,z_n) \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of points on the ellipsoid that converges in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to some $(x,y,z)$. Then $x_n \rightarrow x$, $y_n \rightarrow y$, and $z_n\rightarrow z$. Therefore,
$$
        \frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{4}+\frac{z^{2}}{9} = \lim_{n}\frac{x_n^{2}}{4}+\frac{y_n^{2}}{4}+\frac{z_n^{2}}{9} = \lim_n 1 = 1.
$$
So $(x,y,z)$ is on the ellipsoid, which means the ellipsoid is closed.

You can show compactness using this because, if $\{ (x_n,y_n,z_n) \}$ is any sequence of points on the ellipsoid, then $\{ x_n \}$ is bounded by $2$, $\{ y_n \}$ is bounded by $2$, and $\{ z_n \}$ is bounded by $3$. So you can choose a subsequence of the points that converges in the $x$ coordinate, and then choose a subsequence of the subsequence that converges in the second coordinate (the subsequence of the subsequence will converge in $x$ automatically because a subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent)... continuing, you obtain a subsequence $\{ (x_{n_k},y_{n_k},z_{n_k}) \}$ that converges in all three coordinates; then the argument of the first paragraph shows that the limit of this subsequence will be on the ellipsoid.

Comment: So we know any sequence of points must converge to a point on the ellipsoid, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The set is
$$
E=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\;\middle|\;\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}= 1\right\}
$$
If $\|(x,y,z)\|>3$, then $(x,y,z)\notin E$, because from $x^2+y^2+z^2>9$ we deduce 
$$
\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}
\ge\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{9}+\frac{z^2}{9}>1
$$
and so $(x,y,z)\notin E$. Therefore $E$ is bounded.

Since $E$ is the inverse image of $\{1\}$ under the continuous function
$$
f\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},
\quad
f\colon(x,y,z)\mapsto\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}
$$
the set $E$ is closed.

Note that the Heine-Borel theorem *requires* using the Euclidean metric.

Comment: What is the theorem for pre image of a continuous function, thus closed?

Comment: @SkiesBurn A function is continuous if and only if inverse images of open sets are open, which is equivalent to saying that inverse images of closed sets are closed.

Comment: continuous iff inverse image of open set is open

And since our function is continuous, we know that our closed point $\{1\}$ can't map to an 'open' $E$, so $E$ isn't open, nor clopen, and the only thing left is closed, so it must be closed?

Comment: @SkiesBurn The function is continuous, so the inverse image of the closed set $\{1\}$ is closed. You seem to believe that a set is closed if it's not open, which is false: a set may be neither open nor closed.

Comment: Well then how does 'a function is continuous if and only if inverse images of open sets are open' itself imply that 'inverse images of closed sets are closed'? Given that they aren't opposites, sorry just trying to understand

Comment: @SkiesBurn A set is closed if and only if its complement is open; the inverse image of the complement of a set is the complement of the inverse image of the set.

Comment: I am kindly surprised to see you using `\;\middle|\;` rather than `\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}`.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That would leave too much space: two thick spaces on the left and on the right, because `\middle|` is an Ord atom. The proper way should be `\mathrel{-\mskip\thickmuskip}\middle|\mathrel{-\mskip\thickmuskip}` but in this case it's overkill.

Comment: I knew that `\middle|` by itself produces insufficient spacing. The proper way seems quite an overkill here. But I'll try to remember it for my usual batch of macros. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closure comes from the fact that {0} is closed and the surface itself is the inverse image of {0} of the continuous function x^2/4+y^2/4+z^2/9-1. The boundedness comes from ability of enclosing the surface inside the sphere x^2+y^2+z^2=100